# DataStax AMI hangs on

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, datastax

I am installing Cassandra on Amazon AWS using this tutorial http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMILaunch.html

So far I am using just one node ami-7f33cd08 of type m3-large put in subnet. From the AWS perspective the instance launches, but when I log in I get straight away

```
Cluster started with these options:
--clustername myDSCcluster --totalnodes 1 --version community
Installation started..
```

And *Installation started.* just keeps there with newline being inserted every few seconds.

Anyone came across this thing? Any solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there were a few tickets that came up recently around the same issue, it seems as though something recently changed within the AMI provisioning side in EC2, or this specific configuration of VPCs had never been used before, which seems a bit unlikely.

The current fix is to add an additional entry into /etc/hostname to get rid of the stderr output that occurs after each sudo command. This in turn doesn't get flagged as an error on the provisioning side.

This has been fixed and patched as documented on this ticket:
https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI/issues/51.

If you spot any additional issues, feel free to create another ticket there.

Going forward, just launch another set of instances using the same user-data and you should be up and running.